# Why is the order/weight of blocks added to region not saved?

Tags: 9, layout-builder

I have used layout builder to manage display on the default display of a content type.I have not selected "overrides allowed" so that this is the global layout for this content type. I see the "You are editing the layout template for all {{MyType}} content items."

Within one of the sections I am adding 4 blocks to a single region then dragging them into the correct order. However the order or weight of the blocks is not saving.

I select "Manage layout", drag the blocks into order, click "Save layout".
If I click "Manage layout" again they have reverted to the previous order.

What I have tried:
I have tried exporting the config, swapping two of the weights and re-importing. This also has no effect.

I have tried exporting the config, re-ordering the components in the config file including editing the weights to match and then re-importing. This does work.

Any idea what I can do next time I add blocks out of order short of removing them all or hand editing the config file?